# android screen blurred after switch from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: android, hdmi, edid

I am working on an nvidia jetson tk1 development board with android 4.4 system. I have connected the board with a screen through hdmi interface. The problem is that whenever I switch the screen to landscape mode the screen will be blurred, I mean have some jetter irregular lines when screen refreshing. I rotate the screen with the builtin app.
As I am not familar with the dsi architecture, could anyone help to indicate which module I should check, edid, hdmi or android?
Thanks.